# OnSelectionChanged MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

Tarde,

Como posso fazer para chamar o evento OnSelecionChanged de um DDL utilizando MVC?

Tenho o seguinte DDL:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, ViewBag.Type as SelectList, "-- Select --", new { id = "ddlType", onchange = "onchange()" })
```

E baseado no item selecionado nesse DDL, dou um Hidden em outro DDL, ou seja, esse 2º DDL só será mostrado se uma opção específica do 1º DDL for marcada.

O 2º DDL é esse:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SimilarId, ViewBag.SimilarId as SelectList, "-- Select --", new { id = "ddlSimilarId" })
```

PS: Também queria fazer isso para um RadioButton..

Agradeço desde já.

**EDIT**

Essa *Bundle* já é referenciada na "Master Page" _Layout..
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Fiz dessa forma, não acontece nada, o que ainda falta?

```
@section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function onchange() {

        if (document.getElementById("ddlType").value == "Eletronic") {
            document.getElementById("ddlSimilarId").disabled = "disabled";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Tentei assim também:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
        $(function () {
            $("#ddlType").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "Eletronic") {
                    $("#ddlSimilar").disabled = "disabled";
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Antes de mais nada, acho que vale a pena conhecer como funciona o jQuery](http://jquerybrasil.org/tutoriais/).

O correto para o seu caso é este *Bundle* aqui:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Não sei qual a sua lógica, mas um começo seria algo assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idDaDropDownList").change(function() {
       if ($(this).val() == "Algum valor") {
           // Coloque aqui a lógica
       }
    });

    $("#idDaDropDownList").trigger('change');
});
```

---

Como não conheço seu código, vou dar algumas sugestões de tutoriais de como você pode depurar o JavaScript escrito no seu navegador de escolha:

- [Depurando JavaScript no Google Chrome](http://www.devmedia.com.br/depurando-javascript-com-google-chrome/28367);
- [Depurando JavaScript no Mozilla Firefox](http://www.devmedia.com.br/depurando-javascript-no-mozilla-firefox/28387)

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, tentei utilizar seu código, mas não funcionou. 
Dei uma olhada no link, e cheguei a uma função (está no tópico principal), se puder, dá uma olhada, grato.

Comment: @developer033 Atualizei a resposta.